# GitHub search: how to exclude multiple authors from the search result?

Tags: github, search, pull-request

I know I can exclude one author by `-author:someone`, but it looks like excluding 2 authors doesn't work: `-author:user1 -author:user2`. The result will include the `user2`.

I read [GitHub search syntax doc](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#filter-qualifiers-based-on-exclusion) but could find a solution.

Is there a way to exclude 2 authors at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to be facing the same issue as you for some reason. I tried searching `"rust" in:name`, to show all repos matching the exact phrase `"rust"`, which gave me the following results (you can view them on GitHub [**here**](https://github.com/search?q=%22rust%22+in%3Aname&type=Repositories)):

[**screenshot of searching *"rust" in:name on GitHub***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S64Zy.png)

I then searched `"rust" in:name -user:rust-lang -user:TheAlgorithms -user:tensorflow` (view them on GitHub [**here**](https://github.com/search?q=%22rust%22+in%3Aname+-user%3Arust-lang+-user%3ATheAlgorithms+-user%3Atensorflow&type=Repositories)) to exclude the first 3 authors from the results, which worked a charm:

[**screenshot of searching *"rust" in:name -user:rust-lang -user:TheAlgorithms -user:tensorflow* on GitHub**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4Hm.png)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in the GitHub search (the search box on the upper left corner), and it's working. But it doesn't work in the search box on the Pull Requests or Issues page. Is there a way to make it work too?